# Android 2.3 and Phonegap, navigator.online does not work

Tags: android, html, cordova

I tested navigator.online and it worked until I built the app with PhoneGap, after that,  navigator.online always returned true.
Does anybody know how can I un-cache or refresh this value? I need it on "on click" events.

Comment: Yeah it is broken in the WebView component that PhoneGap uses but works fine in the Browser. It looks like we may be able to fix it for 2.2 though. In the meantime use what @Rishi has posted.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is now fixed in the latest (currently 2.7.0 ) version of Phonegap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing this issue while I was developing an application.

What I used is:

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
```

These events will be fired when the device is disconnected or connected to internet on the fly.

You can store some global variables in the function

```
function onOnline(){}
```

and

```
function onOffline(){}
```

Than check the values of those global variables and do whatever you want to according to the value.